# To retrieve an email ID from a rule chain in ThingsBoard

Tags: node-red, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

[image]

I have the Factory 1 ID, and I need to obtain the email address of the security personnel from the user group. I'm seeking assistance on how to retrieve data from the user group using ThingsBoard rule chain. Is there a specific node for extracting information from a user group within the rule chain?

I also attached hierarchy diagram for better understand.

https://ibb.co/DzXCXWJ

I want data from user group for particular customer.